# ¿Cómo mantener a un servidor escuchando un puerto?

Tags: c#, ftp

Estoy implementando un servidor FTP basandome en la informacion del siguiente enlace:

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/380769/Creating-an-FTP-Server-in-Csharp-with-IPv-Support

Siguiendo este tutorial, no sé que poner en la clase principal para hacer que el servidor se mantenga conectado durante un tiempo indeterminado escuchando en puerto 21 para recibir las solicitudes.

He intentado ciclar con un while el servidor, pero solo me ha provocado errores. Disculpen si mi pregunta es muy noob pero realmente soy nuevo en esto.

Les agradezco su atención.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar la clase TcpListener. Aquí tienes un ejemplo: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener(v=vs.110).aspx

Este es el código:

```
public static void Main()
  { 
    TcpListener server=null;   
    try
    {
      // Set the TcpListener on port 13000.
      Int32 port = 13000;
      IPAddress localAddr = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");

      // TcpListener server = new TcpListener(port);
      server = new TcpListener(localAddr, port);

      // Start listening for client requests.
      server.Start();

      // Buffer for reading data
      Byte[] bytes = new Byte[256];
      String data = null;

      // Enter the listening loop.
      while(true) 
      {
        Console.Write("Waiting for a connection... ");

        // Perform a blocking call to accept requests.
        // You could also user server.AcceptSocket() here.
        TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();            
        Console.WriteLine("Connected!");

        data = null;

        // Get a stream object for reading and writing
        NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

        int i;

        // Loop to receive all the data sent by the client.
        while((i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length))!=0) 
        {   
          // Translate data bytes to a ASCII string.
          data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, i);
          Console.WriteLine("Received: {0}", data);

          // Process the data sent by the client.
          data = data.ToUpper();

          byte[] msg = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);

          // Send back a response.
          stream.Write(msg, 0, msg.Length);
          Console.WriteLine("Sent: {0}", data);            
        }

        // Shutdown and end connection
        client.Close();
      }
    }
    catch(SocketException e)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("SocketException: {0}", e);
    }
    finally
    {
       // Stop listening for new clients.
       server.Stop();
    }


    Console.WriteLine("\nHit enter to continue...");
    Console.Read();
  }
```